# Another problem setting a cell formula with vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a set Vlookup formula that I am trying to set for all cells in a column but the sheet where I add these formulas is separated by groups and boiler plate template info. I have code that selects all the right cells and positions everything ready to enter the formula but always get "Application-defined or object-defined" error when I try to set the cell.

```
areaFormula = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],inventory.csv!iValue,10,FALSE)
```

Another sub adjusts the formula based on the inventory csv.

```
Dim lRow As Integer
    Dim datAddress As String
    lRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    datAddress = "$A$1:$L$" & lRow
    GetVPIZone = Replace(s, "iValue", datAddress)
```

After the formula is adjusted the value is passed back to the original function and we try to set the cell.formula

```
            If PEEK(ActiveCell) Then
                ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = areaFormula
                Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
                Selection.FillDown
                Selection.Copy
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                FilterAndSort
                Selection.End(xlDown).Select
                xLastRow = Selection.Row
                Selection.Offset(2, 0).Select
            Else
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there data below the cells that are selected? If there is a table, the filldown will stop there. If you are just putting this formula into a blank cell, it fills down to infinity (row 1,048,576) which throws the error

Comment: + when you ajust formula with `Replace(s, "iValue", datAddress)`, you are mixing R1C1 and A1 notations such as `RC[-1]` and `"$A$1:$L$..."`. Use address like `"R1C1:R...C12"` instead `"$A$1:$L$..."`  where `...` is row number

Comment: In your formula, you need to close it out with another "

Comment: There is data in the cells that are selected. I verify to make sure it only selects the the first row of each section and then does the range(selection, selection.End(xlDown)).select to grab from first to last row.

@АлексейР
So proper R1C1 notation if I wanted columns A through L=  R1C1:R246C11?

Comment: Thank you @АлексейР. That fixed it. I changed the code as below and it works now.

    **datAddress = "R1C1:R" & lRow & "C11"**

**GetVPIZone = Replace(s, "iValue", datAddress)**